# Passing the limit of a sequence of functions under the integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Ok so I have to evaluate the following:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} n^2\sin\left( \left(\frac{x}{n} \right)^2 \right) e^{-x^2} \,dx$$

Which is no problem at all when we put the limit in.

My problem is justifying the limit step. I am quite sure that I have to use Dominated Convergence Theorem- need to bound $|f_k|$'s by some $g$ that is integrable but I am having major issues figuring it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $|\sin x | \leqslant |x| \implies n^2 |\sin[(x/n)^2]|e^{-x^2} \leqslant x^2e^{-x^2}$

Comment: Yes but $x^2$ is not integrable. I could use it for (0,1) interval. But what about $(0, \infty ) $ ?

So the limit actually bounds it? It is an increasing function?

Comment: How about $x^2e^{-x^2}$? We have $|f_n(x)|$ dominated by the integrable $g(x) = x^2e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: If it is true for all n then the limit itself will do the job but I can't see how that second inequality holds. In particular why $n^2| sin[ (x/n)^2] | \leq x^2$ ?
I guess it is obvious but I am missing the point somehow at 4 am..

Comment: The inequality $|\sin y| \leqslant |y|$ is well-known and holds for all $y$.  Choose $ y = (x/n)^2$.   Hence $n^2|\sin[(x/n)^2]| \leqslant n^2 (x/n)^2 = x^2$.

Comment: Shoot. Ok its all done. Thank you very much

Comment: @John Smith: You're welcome.